# Azure DevOps: Bash step - 'No such device or address' error when redirecting to /dev/stdout

Tags: bash, azure-devops, stdout

I have a very simple bash step in Azure DevOps pipeline, which is trying to redirect output to /dev/stdout.
It is as simple as:

```
- bash: |
        echo "Hello World to dev stdout" > /dev/stdout
```

Unfortunately, it results in the error:
`/dev/stdout: No such device or address`

The job which runs provided bash step has docker image specified like the following:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
```

I've already tried redirection to bunch of other devices (/dev/tty, dev/pts/0, /proc/self/fd/1 etc.) - all results in the same error. The only redirection which works is to file or to /dev/null.

But when I'm doing `ls -la /dev` I still can see all devices present in output, e.g. stdout, tty.

Has anyone already faced with such an issue or have any clue how to bypass this? Maybe there is some other device I can use as an output terminal in ADO bash step? Any help would be appreciated.

--> adding output of `ls -la /proc/self/fd` command:

```
lrwx------ 1 vsts docker 64 May 16 10:58 0 -> socket:[27963]
lrwx------ 1 vsts docker 64 May 16 10:58 1 -> socket:[27965]
lr-x------ 1 vsts docker 64 May 16 10:58 125 -> pipe:[24752]
l-wx------ 1 vsts docker 64 May 16 10:58 128 -> pipe:[24753]
lrwx------ 1 vsts docker 64 May 16 10:58 2 -> socket:[27967]
lr-x------ 1 vsts docker 64 May 16 10:58 3 -> /proc/2148/fd
```

Comment: `/dev/stdout` is just a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/1`. You can use that address directly on distros that don't have it. (It also has special handling in bash, but it's very believable that the "bash" action would be misleadingly named and actually run `sh`; even people who should know better often conflate the two).

Comment: The other thing is that `/dev/stdout`-- FD 1 of the current process -- is where `echo` sends its output _by default_, so that redirection will never do anything useful. If that content wasn't already reaching the terminal, that means stdout is redirected to somewhere other than the terminal when the command runs. Either way, redirecting to stdout is doing extra work to send something to the same place it would have gone anyhow.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've already tried `/proc/self/fd/1` - same error. Example with echo I've provided is just a narrowed down snippet to demonstrate/replicate the problem.

Comment: Much more interesting than listing /dev would be listing /proc/self/fd.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Appended output to my question's body.

Comment: Thank you. At present point, this smells a lot like sandboxing (or some other SELinux-like security overlay), but that's not easy to validate without setting up an equivalent environment. Anyhow, _terminal output_ is a completely different thing -- as I described above, `/dev/fd/1`, `/dev/stdout`, etc etc all refer to the socket that content is already going to by default after all the redirections were performed; they don't go to the terminal so they wouldn't achieve your goal of sending output direct to the terminal even if you _could_ open them successfully.